# Find regular expression for my twitter time stamp (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I am trying to fix my twitter feed and I wanted to link my tweet's time stamp to each individual tweet's page.

I created my function using a regular expression for my tweet's time stamp but it just doesn't seem to work.

The format of the time stamp is `about xx minute(s)/hour(s)/day(s) ago` and I used the bellow regular expression to describe it.

```
$tweet="/about + /[0-9] + / minute[s]|day[s] ago/";
```

It might be completely wrong, but I'm new in this, and I'd appreciate any help.

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: My feed has a format of: about xx minute(s)/hour(s)/day(s) ago: tweet including links for hashtags/usernames/urls.

My function basically checks if anything in [about xx minute(s)/hour(s)/day(s) ago] matches the $tweet format and then it passes the https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=whatever&count=2 url to it.

The thing is that when the function runs, all I get back is the subject (about xx minute(s)/hour(s)/day(s) ago) back. I read in php.net that when you get the subject back, it means that no maches were found, which made me come to the conclusion that my regular expression was wrong.

So, I guess what I'm trying to find out is whether the regex I used is wrong or right.

Comment: Where do you get this time format? Doesn't twitters API return full datetime like `Fri Apr 09 12:53:54 +0000 2010` ?

Comment: It might be wrong, but unless you don't tell us what is wrong for you (e.g. how do your expectations (which are they btw?) differ from your experiences with that subject), there hardly is any question to answer. Also give an example of your twitter feed so it becomes more clear what you ask about. Regex are a language of it's own so it's something new to learn, I can understand that, but if it's that general, this is a good website: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: The twitter time stamp does come in the format you mentioned, however I changed it to the one mentioned above. What I have been trying to do is add links on hashtags/urls and usernames with a function using preg_replace. I succesfully did that and now I wanted to do the same for the timestamp that is shown on the tweet (same way it works in twitter, you click on the timestamp and you get redirected to a web page of that individual tweet). I'll edit my answer above for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/about ([0-9]+) (minute[s]?|hour[s]?|day[s]?) ago/', $string, $matches);
```

#### Outputs

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'about 53 hour ago' (length=17)
  1 => string '53' (length=2)
  2 => string 'hour' (length=4)

array (size=3)
  0 => string 'about 20 minutes ago' (length=20)
  1 => string '20' (length=2)
  2 => string 'minutes' (length=7)

array (size=3)
  0 => string 'about 2 day ago' (length=15)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string 'day' (length=3)
```

Comment: this regex worked perfectly after I added brackets between about and ago. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regular expression:

```
about [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}
```

in order to make sure about the syntax you generate you can test it using online regex testers website. Here is an example website: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 /about + /[0-9] + / minute[s]|day[s] ago/
        ^        ^
        |        |
        |        |
    repetition one or more: here one or more space then followed 
    by another space
```

I guess this is not what you were looking for. There are more issues but I tend to keep things simple and do one fix at a time. Why not start with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

about xx minute(s)/hour(s)/day(s) ago

```
about [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) ago
```